# Simple Harmonic Motion; Tension in Elastic rope

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I'm struggling to model this question out correctly.

A glider and its pilot have total mass $230$ kg. The glider lands on a horizontal airstrip and when its speed is $16$ m/s it hooks on to the mid-point of a light elastic rope of natural length $40$ m and modulus of elasticity $4000$ N. The ends of the rope are fixed to points $A$ and $B$ of the airstrip, where $AB = 40$ m. When the glider hooks on to the rope, the glider is moving perpendicular to $AB$. The modelling assumptions are that the glider may be treated as a particle moving horizontally, and that the only horizontal force acting results from the tension in the rope.

Find

$a)$ the speed of the glider when it has moved $15$ m past the mid-point of $AB$,

$b)$ the displacement from the mid-point of AB when the glider first comes instantaneously to rest,

$c)$ the acceleration of the glider when it first comes instantaneously to rest.

Please, help.

Comment: a figure will help

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Please try to add your own thoughts. Also, a picture may help to visualize the problem better. :)